# putting every 3rd row of a matrix in a new matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to create 3 matrices from a bigger matrix.
The new matrices should contain:

- new matrix 1: the `1st, 4th, 7th....` element of the old matrix
- new matrix 2: the `2nd, 5th, 8th....` element of the old matrix
- new matrix 3: the `3rd, 6th, 9th....` element of the old matrix

So if my matrix looks like this:

```
    m<-matrix(c(1:3),nrow=12, ncol=2)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    3    3
 [4,]    1    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    3    3
 [7,]    1    1
 [8,]    2    2
 [9,]    3    3
[10,]    1    1
[11,]    2    2
[12,]    3    3
```

I tried it with a for loop like this

```
for(i in 1:4){
  m1<-m[i+3,]
  m2<-m[i+4,]
  m3<-m[i+5,]
}
```

But this not only would not be able to give me the 1st/2nd/3rd rows, but also doesn't give me all rows.

There has to be a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take advantage of the cycling rule of indexing in R:

```
m[c(T, F, F),]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
# [3,]    1    1
# [4,]    1    1

m[c(F, T, F),]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    2
# [2,]    2    2
# [3,]    2    2
# [4,]    2    2

m[c(F, F, T),]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3    3
# [2,]    3    3
# [3,]    3    3
# [4,]    3    3
```

When we are indexing the matrix with vectors which have different length from the number of rows of the matrix, the vector here which has a smaller length will get cycled until their lengths match, so for instance, the first case, the actual indexing vector is extended to `c(T, F, F, T, F, F, T, F, F)` which will pick up the first, fourth and seventh row as expected. The same goes for case two and three.

Comment: This works amazingly. Thank you. Could you explain why it works? Would be good to understand :)

Comment: @KevinRoth You actually used the cycling rule yourself when creating your example matrix `m` above without even realizing it :)

Comment: It was a constructed example to simplify the question. Didn't want to share my actual data ;) But it worked there as well, so I am very happy, THANKS

Answer (score 5):

We can use `seq` to do this.  This will be faster for big datasets.

```
 m[seq(1, nrow(m), by =3),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Or we could do:

```
m[seq(nrow(m))%%3==1,] # 1th, 3th, 7th, ...
m[seq(nrow(m))%%3==2,] # 2th, 5th, 8th, ...
m[seq(nrow(m))%%3==0,] # 3th, 6th, 9th, ...
```

**BENCHMARKING**

```
library(microbenchmark)

m <- matrix(c(1:3),nrow=12, ncol=2)

func_Psidom <- function(m){m[c(T, F, F),]}
func_akrun <- function(m){ m[seq(1, nrow(m), by =3),]}
func_42 <- function(m){ m[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE), ]}
func_m0h3n <- function(m){m[seq(nrow(m))%%3==1,]}

r <- func_Psidom(m)
all(func_akrun(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_42(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_m0h3n(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(func_Psidom(m), func_akrun(m), func_42(m), func_m0h3n(m))

# Unit: microseconds
           # expr    min     lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 # func_Psidom(m)  2.566  3.850  4.49990  4.2780  4.7050  14.543   100
  # func_akrun(m) 38.923 39.779 43.58536 40.2065 41.0615 252.359   100
     # func_42(m)  2.994  3.422  4.13628  4.2770  4.7050  13.688   100
  # func_m0h3n(m) 18.820 20.103 22.37447 20.7445 21.3860 104.365   100

# ============================================================

m <- matrix(c(1:3),nrow=1200, ncol=2)
r <- func_Psidom(m)
all(func_akrun(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_42(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_m0h3n(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(func_Psidom(m), func_akrun(m), func_42(m), func_m0h3n(m))

# Unit: microseconds
           # expr    min      lq     mean median     uq      max neval
 # func_Psidom(m) 12.832 13.6875 14.41458 14.542 14.543   22.242   100
  # func_akrun(m) 56.033 57.3150 65.17700 57.743 58.599  289.998   100
     # func_42(m) 12.832 13.4735 14.76962 14.115 14.543   56.032   100
  # func_m0h3n(m) 76.990 78.2730 97.82522 78.702 79.557 1873.437   100

# ============================================================

m <- matrix(c(1:3),nrow=120000, ncol=2)
r <- func_Psidom(m)
all(func_akrun(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_42(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE
all(func_m0h3n(m)==r)
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(func_Psidom(m), func_akrun(m), func_42(m), func_m0h3n(m))

# Unit: microseconds
           # expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 # func_Psidom(m)  963.665  978.6355 1168.161 1026.113 1076.798  3648.498   100
  # func_akrun(m) 1674.117 1787.6785 2808.231 1890.760 2145.043 58450.377   100
     # func_42(m)  960.672  976.2835 1244.467 1033.812 1115.507  3114.268   100
  # func_m0h3n(m) 5817.920 6127.8070 7697.345 7455.895 8055.565 62414.963   100
```

Comment: Good use of microbenchmark.  I thought the recycling would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

Logical vectors get recycled to the length of the number of rows or columns when matrix indexing:

```
 m[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE), ]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    1
[3,]    1    1
[4,]    1    1

m[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)[c(2,1,3)], ]  # the numeric vector permutes the logical values

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    2    2
[3,]    2    2
[4,]    2    2

m[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)[c(2,3,1)], ]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    3
[2,]    3    3
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    3    3
```